# change data when no match found among two array list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 array list

**Array 1**

```
var array1=[{default:true ,name:"type"},{default:true ,name:"id"},{default:true ,name:"status"}]
```

**Array 2**

```
var array2=[{default:true ,name:"id"},{default:true ,name:"status"}]
```

Now I want the third array such as

**Array3**

```
var array3=[{default:false ,name:"type"}]
```

where name doesnt match, its default value should become false

Comment: So loop over the arrays and find indexes that do not have a match.

Comment: I am trying , but its not working

Comment: What did you try? Show an attempt

Comment: to clarify, you want array3 to contain all objects that are not present in BOTH array1 and array2?

Answer (score 0):

To only find missing values from `array1`:

```js
var array1=[{default:true ,name:"type"},{default:true ,name:"id"},{default:true ,name:"status"}];

var array2=[{default:true ,name:"id"},{default:true ,name:"status"}]

var array3 = array1.filter(function(val){
  return array2.filter(function(val2){ return val.name == val2.name }).length == 0;
}).map(function(v) {
  return {default:false, name:v.name};
});

console.log(array3);
```

To find missing values from `array1` *and* `array2`:

```js
var array1=[{default:true ,name:"type"},{default:true ,name:"id"},{default:true ,name:"status"}];

var array2=[{default:true ,name:"id"},{default:true ,name:"status"}]

var array3 = array1.filter(function(val){
  return array2.filter(function(val2){ return val.name == val2.name }).length == 0;
}).concat(array2.filter(function(val){
  return array1.filter(function(val2){ return val.name == val2.name }).length == 0;
})).map(function(v) {
  return {default:false, name:v.name};
})

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hash table and take it as reference which items should be in the result array.

```js
var array1 = [{ default: true, name: "type" }, { default: true, name: "id" }, { default: true, name: "status" }],
    array2 = [{ default: true, name: "id" }, { default: true, name: "status" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

array2.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.name] = true;
});

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.name] || result.push({ default: false, name: a.name });
});
    
console.log(result);
```